# Schedule an Action in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I'm attempting to learn the ins and outs of Quartz.NET but I'm not making much headway getting what I consider to be a very simple task done.

I have a method that receives an Action and a DateTime and I just need to schedule action X to run at time Y.

This seems simple but JobBuilder.Create() requires a type argument that implements IJob... but I don't the slightest inkling what the Action I receive does until I have it. I can't have some class with a well-defined Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) method because I just don't have that information at compile time.

I can't change my method's signature either. I get an Action and a DateTime, that is not my decision.

Can Quartz genuinely not handle this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Quartz.Net is the right tool to achieve what you're looking for.
It would be to complicated to do it with it.

I would suggest you to switch to another tool like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler):

```
Install-Package FluentScheduler
```

and then you could do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScheduleAction(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(4), Action1, "A", "B");
        ScheduleAction(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(8), Action1, "C", "D");
        ScheduleAction(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(12), Action1, "E", "F");

        Console.WriteLine("Running ...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ScheduleAction(DateTime runOnceAt, Action<string, string> action, string param1, string param2)
    {
        FluentScheduler.TaskManager.AddTask(() =>
        {
            action.Invoke(param1, param2);

        }, x => x.WithName("MyTask").ToRunOnceAt(runOnceAt));
    }

    private static void Action1(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Action 1 {0} - {1}", param1, param2);
    }

    private static void Action2(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Action 2 {0} - {1}", param1, param2);
    }

    private static void Action3(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Action 3 {0} - {1}", param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's funny. For all it's supposed "power", Quartz can't do such a simple thing.

Comment: Quartz.Net is really powerful but I guest it's overly complicated for simple tasks like fire-and-forget. I've recently switched to [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/) for those kind of things. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Quartz has this particular ability built-in, but it is trivial to implement it on top of Quartz's existing APIs:

```
class RunActionJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var action = context.MergedJobDataMap["action"] as Action;
        action();
    }
}

public static JobBuilder ActionJob(Action action)
{
    return JobBuilder
        .Create<RunActionJob>()
        .SetJobData(new JobDataMap
        {
            {"action", action}
        });
}

// Usage:

var job = ActionJob(() => Console.WriteLine("task 1..."))
    .WithIdentity("task1", "group1")
    .Build();
```